# Extracting columnar data correctly as it is in the file

Tags: python-2.7

Suppose i have tabular column as below.Now i want to extract the column wise data.I tried extracting data by creating a list.But it is extracting the first row correctly but from second row onwards there is space i.e under CEN/4.Now my code considers zeroth column has 5.0001e-1 form second row,it starts reading from there. How to extract the data correctly coulmn wise.output is  scrambled.

```
0    1   25    CEN/4  -5.000000E-01  -3.607026E+04 -5.747796E+03 -8.912796E+02   -88.3178  
                       5.000000E-01   3.607026E+04  5.747796E+03  8.912796E+02     1.6822   

         27           -5.000000E-01  -3.641444E+04 -5.783247E+03 -8.912796E+02   -88.3347  
                       5.000000E-01   3.641444E+04  5.783247E+03  8.912796E+02     1.6653

         28           -5.000000E-01  -3.641444E+04 -5.712346E+03 -8.912796E+02   -88.3386  
                       5.000000E-01   3.641444E+04  5.712346E+03  8.912796E+02  


my code is :
f1=open('newdata1.txt','w')
L = []
for index, line in enumerate(open('Trial_1.txt','r')):
#print index
   if index < 0: #skip first 5 lines
      continue
   else:
      line =line.split()
      L.append('%s\t%s\t %s\n' %(line[0], line[1],line[2]))


f1.writelines(L)

f1.close()



my output looks like this:
    0   1   CEN/4   -5.000000E-01    -5.120107E+04
   5.000000E-01 5.120107E+04    1.028093E+04    5.979930E+03     8.1461
```

i want columnar data as it is in the file.How to do that.I am a bgeinner

Answer (score 0):

its hard to tell from the way the input data is presented in your question, but Im guessing your file is using tabs to separate columns, in any case, consider using python csv module with the relevant delimiter like:

```
import csv
with open('input.csv') as f_in, open('newdata1', 'w') as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

see [python csv module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for further details